# How to run javascript code when table design is in controller of laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a table design in the controller of laravel.

it is populated in a form designed in blade via ajax call.

my table looks as this:

```
if(count($sublaw_details)>0)
                {
                    $res_div.='<table width="100%" border="0"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
                    $res_div.='<tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                                        <strong>'.$law_details->lm_id.' ('.$law_details->law_name.')</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" value="'.$start_date.'" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY (Start Date)" onchange="showData();" name="law_start_date[]" id="law_start_date" att_law_id="'.$lawdata[$i].'"  class="date-picker required locationformstyle locationparentsd dynamiclocationparentsd'.$lawdata[$i].'">
                                        <span class="error" style="visibility: visible" id="er"  name="er">Required</span>                                     
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td>
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" placeholder="Law Registration No." name="law_reg_no" id="law_reg_no" class="locationformstyle required">
                              </td>
                              </tr>';

                    foreach($sublaw_details as $sublawdetails)
                    {
                        if (in_array($sublawdetails->sublaw_id, $sublawdata))
                        {
                            $res_div.='<tr>
            <td width="220">Start Date: <input type="text" name="sub_law_start_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker dynamiclocationparentsd'.$lawdata[$i].'" att_law_id="'.$lawdata[$i].'"> </td>
            <td width="220">End Date: <input type="text"  name="sub_law_end_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker"></td>
            <td align="left"><strong>'.$sublawdetails->lms_id.' ('.$sublawdetails->sub_law_name.')</strong>
            <input type="hidden" class="locationformstyle" name="company_sub_laws[]" value="'.$sublawdetails->sublaw_id.'">
            </td>
            </tr>
            ';
                        }
                    }
                    $res_div.='</table>';
                }
```

I want to hide the span when start date is selected

Here is the Javascript code I have written.

```
<script> function showData() { 
      document.getElementById("er").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: post your javascript code

Comment: <script>
function showData()
{                                                                                                document.getElementById("er").style.visibility = "hidden";
 }</script>

Comment: this script is not working in controller

Comment: Why are you creating this in your controller?

Comment: I would move this view code to a blade file

Comment: But you also use this code directly in blade file

Comment: add this script in respective view.

Comment: onchange is not working if i write this script in respective view

Comment: @Deb: Could you please provide your onchange code?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that controller is not for creating views. It just for routing or simply communicator between the views and database layers.

Here is a change for controller:

- Create new view lets say table.blade.php.
- In your controller add below statements

  $tableViewInString = view('table',array_of_parameters)->__toString();
- Return this string view as a response for your AJAX call.

If you are using jQUery then I would suggest following the way to do it.

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $("#IDOFSPAN").hide();
    }
});
```